# Render Jinja String While Keeping Linebreaks in Django

Tags: django, jinja2

I have a jinja string (I set it to be `"my_string": "My name is<br>John!"`) rendered in a Django template:

```
{{ my_string }}
```

This is my view:

```
def my_view(request):
    context={"my_string":"My name is<br>John!"}
    return render(request, 'myview.html', context)
```

When rendered, it shows this in the html page:

```
My name is<br>John!
```

However, I want the line break to actually cause a line break, like this:

```
My name is
John!
```

What do I need to do differently? Thanks!!

Comment: Add your view also...

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I added my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`safe`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) filter

```
{{ my_string|safe }}
```